# How to ping Docker-Container inside host network?

Tags: docker, containers, remote-access, ping, host

I'm working with Docker containers for a while now but can't figure out how to ping docker containers which are part of my host network.

So until now I created my containers specifing the name and networks flags like described in many tutorials like: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-ping-docker-container-from-another-container-by-name

Where I am able to create a network and afterwards run my containers in these networks for example like:

```
docker run -d --name web1  -n testnetwork
docker run -d --name web2  -n testnetwork
```

That would enable me to ping my containers from each other with:

```
docker exec -it web1 bash # enter container
ping web2 #ping second container
```

Now I have to use a given application which only runs in the "host" network for now. To access this container from my other containers they have to be in the same network (== "host").

But It seems like I cant ping my containers from each other anymore. I'm also unable to ping my containers from my host machine using their name.

Did I overlooked something?

Any help would be appreciated!
Best regards

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you set `--network host`, you basically disable Docker's entire networking stack.  Among other things, that disables normal inter-container communications: if you're using host networking you can't call another container by its name.  Host networking is very rarely necessary (and doesn't work well on some host platforms); the first thing I'd look at is whether you can switch back to standard (bridged) networking.

If you *do* run a container with `--network host`, it's indistinguishable from other processes running on that host.  That means you can't directly send ICMP packets to it, any more than you can **ping**(1) your ssh daemon or Web browser.  You need to connect to the container using the host's IP address or DNS name, even from other containers on the same host.  [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach?rq=1) discusses several ways to do this.

(I don't think you can customize the behavior of Docker or Linux when a container receives an ICMP ECHO packet; **ping**(1) a container doesn't seem that useful.)